# Fourier Series generated by a function and periodic with $2\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the Fourier series (in exponential form) generated by a function $f$ which is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ and periodic with period $2\pi$ , say

$$f(x)\sim\sum_{n = - \infty }^{+ \infty }\alpha _{n}e^{inx}.$$

Assume also that the derivative $f '\in \mathbb{R}$  on $[0,2\pi]$.

a.) Prove that the series $\sum_{n = - \infty }^{+ \infty }n^{2}\left | \alpha _{n} \right |^{2}$ converges; then use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to deduce that $\sum_{n = - \infty }^{+ \infty }\left | \alpha _{n} \right |$ converges.

b.) From (a), deduce that the series $\sum_{n = - \infty }^{+ \infty }\alpha _{n}e^{inx}$ converges uniformly to a continuous sum function $g$ on $[0,2\pi]$. Then prove that $f=g$.

Comment: As usual:  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time showing showing that the series is piecewise differentiable so it can converge pointwise

Comment: the series i meant was the first one mentioned in letter a. Letter b i figured out last night so that one isnt necessary to be helped on.